# Declaring variable type based on a column type

Tags: sql-server, variables, types, declaration

In Oracle's PL-SQL, you can declare a variable and define its type based on a table column:

```
declare var1 table.column%TYPE;
```

Is it possible to do something similar in MS SQL Server?

Comment: I believe this is the ONLY thing I like about Oracle over Sql-Server.  #outCursorsStink   :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No you can't do this. The closest equivalent is [`User-Defined Data Types`](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1628). This will give you a layer of abstraction that may help, but it is not the same as deriving a type from a column.

Comment: I've been looking for info on this.  Just wondering, is this still the case eight years later?  This was answered in 2010 and I'm posting this in 2018.

Comment: I wish SqlServer would implement this.  When I change an INT to BIGINT, I gotta go hunt down a bunch of variable declares.

Comment: Thats really pathetic that in 2019 it is still available and oracle has this features from years

Answer (score 7):

It may skirt the real issue, but you can "cheat" a little bit by

```
Select *
INTO #tmp
From MyTable
Where 1 = 0
```

Will automatically create a temp table with all columns with correct data types.