# Get column creation datatype for declaration

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a quick way to get a string containing the sql datatype required for a column declaration, based on column/column information in the database.

For example I'd want strings returned such as:

```
varchar(200)
datetime
numeric(35,5)
```

Obviously I can get the information required to generate this myself from `SYS.COLUMNS` or from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and start handling those, but I wanted a (preferably MS provided) way to turn the datatype/maxlength/precision/scale information into the column declaration data type automatically.

I would guess that if there is a standard way to do this it would handle all possible data types, which would be a pain to try to cover manually.

EDIT: Sorry - It seems I've not been clear enough on what I want.

As an example, when you script a table for `CREATE` in SSMS, the resulting script contains the datatypes in the formats I want. Is there a way to get these automatically?

EDIT:

OK: One more go:

What I want is a bit like this question:

[Declaring variable type based on a column type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683686/sql-server-declaring-variable-type-based-on-a-column-type)

The difference is that I don't mind having to declare the variable dynamically as I'm working with dynamic SQL already.

Comment: You may check this script (Generate table DDL with t-sql) as reference http://www.stormrage.com/SQLStuff/sp_GetDDL_Latest.txt

Comment: @EricZ: Is this your own or from somewhere else? - Might turn this into a udf that does single columns.

Comment: Do you want user defined data types as well as base types, or just base types?

Comment: @JohnDewey: For what I'm doing base should be enough - the code I've now done deals with Base types. I thought it would be the sort of thing there would be a system udf for!

Comment: @JonEgerton I've had quite a search, and I've found an MSDN post from MVP Erland Sommarskog saying there isn't a system way of doing this. He suggests you can script tables programmatically through C# via SMO - I guess this could be manipulated to just the column definitions but I'm not familiar enough with it to post an answer on how to use it. If you're comfortable with c# then [this post](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/ben_miller/archive/2007/10/03/table-scripting-with-smo-part-1.aspx) might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't know of a proper way, but I've had a go at doing the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns` way. This is not pretty, but does handle database defaults, nullables, etc.

```
SELECT column_name + ' ' + DATA_TYPE + COALESCE('(' + CASE
                                                        WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'XML' THEN NULL
                                                        WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 THEN 'max'
                                                        ELSE Cast(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(5))
                                                      END + ')', '(' + Cast(NUMERIC_PRECISION AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ',' + Cast(NUMERIC_SCALE AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ')', '') + ' ' + CASE IS_NULLABLE
                                                                                                                                                                              WHEN 'YES' THEN 'NULL'
                                                                                                                                                                              ELSE 'NOT NULL'
                                                                                                                                                                            END + COALESCE(' DEFAULT' + COLUMN_DEFAULT, '')
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
WHERE  table_name = 'mytable'
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing I've ended up coding. Apparently the closest this in t-sql is `OBJECT_DEFINITION`, but this doesn't work for tables. There is some stuff about it in MS Connect but it's postponed status.

Comment: @JonEgerton I've been after some SQL Server stuff that "just missed" SQL Server 2005 that they still haven't implemented 3 versions later - so I wouldn't hold your breath! Good luck with it, if there's anything that valuely helps in this answer then feel free to use it.

Comment: One thing, this describes xml cols as xml(max).

Comment: @JonEgerton I didn't have any XML columns in my test db - I guess that's an exception to the rule. I've added a special case for that, it should handle that better now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something from my toolbox. Note that it takes the liberty of converting `TEXT` to `VARCHAR(MAX)`. Opinions may vary but I consider this a feature because I hate `TEXT` types:)

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CASE ORDINAL_POSITION WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE ', ' END   +'['+column_name+'] '
    +c.DATA_TYPE
    +ISNULL('('+CAST(c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(30))+')','')
    +CASE WHEN c.DATA_TYPE IN ('NUMERIC','DECIMAL') THEN
        ISNULL('('+CAST(c.NUMERIC_PRECISION AS VARCHAR(30))+','+CAST(c.NUMERIC_SCALE AS VARCHAR(30))+')','')
        ELSE '' END
    +' ','text(2147483647)','varchar(max)'),'(-1)','(max)')

    -- These last two are optional
    +isnull(CASE WHEN c.IS_NULLABLE='NO' THEN 'NOT ' ELSE NULL END,'')
    +'NULL'
    , 'XML(MAX)','XML')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE TABLE_NAME='MyTable' and TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

**EDIT**: Replace XML(MAX) results with XML

Comment: One thing to note: it declares xml cols as `xml(max)` (Was just trying it against some more intereted col types so see how it coped).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
OBJECT_NAME(c.OBJECT_ID) TableName
,c.name AS ColumnName
,t.name AS TypeName
,c.max_length
,c.PRECISION
,c.scale
FROM sys.columns AS c
JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id
ORDER BY c.OBJECT_ID
```

I fear that either way (information_schema.columns) or the query above, you'll have to "massage" the return set to generate the correct data type declaration.

Comment: As I said in the question, getting this is easy from sys.columns, and not what I'm interested in. I want the compiled data type as per my examples, so that I can use that to declare other variables/columns.

Answer (score 0):

what about the second resultset from `sp_help`? I think you could pretty easily tweak that output to get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with (using SQL Server 2014)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetTypeDeclaration(@schema AS VARCHAR(MAX), @table AS VARCHAR(MAX), @column AS VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @type as SYSNAME
    DECLARE @typeDeclaration as VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @maxLength AS SMALLINT
    DECLARE @precision AS TINYINT
    DECLARE @scale AS TINYINT

    SELECT @type = ty.name, @maxLength = c.max_length, @precision = c.precision, @scale = c.scale
    FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON ty.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
    WHERE t.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(@schema) AND t.name = @table AND c.name = @column

    IF @maxLength <> -1 AND @type IN ('nchar', 'nvarchar', 'nvarbinary')
    BEGIN
        SET @maxLength = @maxLength / 2
    END

    IF @type IN ('binary', 'char', 'nchar')
    BEGIN
        SET @typeDeclaration = @type + '(' + CAST(@maxLength AS VARCHAR) + ')'
    END
    ELSE IF @type IN ('datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'time')
    BEGIN
        SET @typeDeclaration = @type + '(' + CAST(@scale AS VARCHAR) + ')'
    END
    ELSE IF @type IN ('nvarchar', 'nvarbinary', 'varchar', 'varbinary')
    BEGIN
        SET @typeDeclaration = @type + '(' + CASE WHEN @maxLength = -1 THEN 'max' ELSE CAST(@maxLength AS VARCHAR) END + ')'
    END
    ELSE IF @type IN ('decimal', 'numeric')
    BEGIN
        SET @typeDeclaration = @type + '(' + CAST(@precision AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST(@scale AS VARCHAR) + ')'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @typeDeclaration = @type
    END

    RETURN @typeDeclaration
END
```