# SQL Server 2012 - Declaring variable type based on a column type in

Tags: variables, types, sql-server-2012, declaration

In Oracle's PL-SQL, you can declare a variable and define its type based on a table column:

```
declare var1 table.column%TYPE;
```

Is it possible to do something similar in SQL Server **2012**?

Note: my question is same as : [Declaring variable type based on a column type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683686/declaring-variable-type-based-on-a-column-type) but my question focuses on SQL Server 2012

Comment: Nothing new in SQL Server 2012 for this.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for the reply. Can you suggest any way to accomplish the same task with sql server?